# Get number of alpha characters added to a varchar in mysql

Tags: mysql

In a column in MySQL, i have data as shown below.

```
column_1
------------------
TEST00001XXXX
TEST0003302XX
TEST000403XXX
TEST00004
TEST00003444XXXX
```

I want to find the count of number of "X" appended at last of to each string.

NOTE:

- The length of each string before appending "X" is not constant.
- The character "X" is case sensitive. (capital X is added at the end of
  the string).
- The character "X" can be present in-between the string
  also. i need the count of "X" which are appended at the end.

**Expected Result :**

```
column_1           |  column_2
--------------------------------
TEST00001XXXX      | 4
TEST0003302XX      | 2    
TEST000403XXX      | 3
TEST00004          | 0
TEST00003444XXXX   | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**TRIM**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) like this:

```
SELECT column_1, 
       LENGTH(column_1) - LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING 'X' FROM column_1)) AS column_2
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/912256/4)

Answer (score 0):

Using **LENGTH** and **REPLACE** you can achieve this:

```
SELECT column_1, LENGTH(column_1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_1, 'X', '')) AS column_2
```

Sample execution:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (column_1 VARCHAR (100));

INSERT INTO my_table (column_1) VALUES
('TEST00001XXXX'),
('TEST0003302XX'),
('TEST000403XXX'),
('TEST00004'),
('TEST00003444XXXX');

SELECT column_1, LENGTH(column_1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(column_1, 'X', '')) AS column_2
FROM my_table
```

Output:

```
column_1            column_2
--------------------------------
TEST00001XXXX       4
TEST0003302XX       2
TEST000403XXX       3
TEST00004           0
TEST00003444XXXX    4
```

Comment: i understand that, this was answered before i edited my question to include NOTE. With out the 3 conditions mentioned in NOTE, this answer is applicable.